# Is there a way for minizinc/cplex to report the percentage of the search space that has been explored when the time budget is reached?

Tags: cplex, minizinc

I'm relatively new to Minizinc. Let's say you have a model that runs with a time budget, is there a compiler/solver option that can report back the estimated percentage of the search space that was explored?

I would like to see know how much of it was left before the time budget killed the process, and it would also be interesting for me to know how much of the search space was actually necessary to explore to achieve the optimums (I'm using it for optimization). I mentioned CPLEX because my model runs faster with that solver, but I could try some other.

Comment: A way to count the number of visited solutions would be enough too, as I can extrapolate from there